# Dynamic routing gives an error when updating the page Next.js

Tags: next.js, routes, next-router, dynamic-routing

Tell me, there is a problem with dynamic routing. When I click on the link /card/[id] . Then everything works correctly, the id of this card is attached to the path that I clicked on, but if I try to refresh the page after the transition, then I get an error:

[image]

As I understand it, when updating a page from its route, the id is lost, which is why fetch cannot be executed
[image]

```
                            job.map(job=> {
                                return <div className="card" id="c4">
                                    <div className="column" id="contentColumn">
                                        <div className='titleCard'>{sale.title}</div>
                                        <div className='textCard'>{sale.description}</div>                                         
                                        <div className='salaryCard'>{sale.salary}&#8381;</div>
                                        <div className='btnDiv'>
                                            <Link href={{
                                                pathname: '/job/[id]',
                                                query: { id: job.id }
                                            }}>
                                                <button className='btnModal' >More info&#10095;</button>
                                            </Link>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            })
```

Here it successfully switches to `http://localhost:3000/job/cl58a9vii`

On a new page (`http://localhost:3000/job/cl58a9vii` ), I'm doing a useeffect to pull up the data

```
const Job: NextPage = () => {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
    const [description, setDescription] = useState('')
    const [office, setOffice] = useState('')
    const [exp, setExp] = useState('')

    const router = useRouter()
    const { id } = router.query

    useEffect(() => {
        async function start() {
            const res = await fetch('/api/job/' + id, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
            })
            if (res.ok) {
               let job = await res.json()
                console.log(job)
                  setDescription(job.description)
              
           
            }
        }
        start()
    }, [])

    return (
<h1>{description}</h1>
)
```

API

```
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    const { id } = req.query
        if (req.method === 'GET') {
            if (typeof id === 'string') {
                const answer= await db.job.findUnique({
                    where: { 
                        id: id },
                })
                res.send(answer)
```

And at the first download everything works correctly , but when updating this page , an error is issued

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `router` as parameter of `useEffect`

```
useEffect(()=>{
    if (router.isReady) {
        async function start() {
            const res = await fetch('/api/job/' + router.query.id, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
            })
            if (res.ok) {
               let job = await res.json()
                console.log(job)
                setDescription(job.description)
            }
        }
        start()
    }

}, [router.isReady]);
```

Comment: Thanks, it work) If someone else needs it  -  isReady: boolean - Whether the router fields are updated client-side and ready for use. Should only be used inside of useEffect methods and not for conditionally rendering on the server. https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object